# Facebook Login for Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need some help regarding issues in Logging In to my App using the process described in the following link-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone/

Its the new way of logging in using the Facebook app for windows phone.

So following the guide, here's what I have been able to accomplish -

1. Prepare the fb app by entering the Product id
2. Invoking the Login dialog by launching the Uri as follows -

   ```
   fbconnect://authorize?client_id={your-facebook-app-id}&scope={permissions-requested}&redirect_uri=msft-{ProductID}://authorize
   ```
3. The fb app opens and asks my app on fb for access to basic info and friends list.
4. I / User grants the required permissions.
5. My app on windows phone opens again - the problem is here.

The FB app should open my app by requesting a uri - as described in the "Before You Start" section in the above link.

I have setup my app to register for uri association as described here -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

I have done this step correctly - I checked this by creating another app and launching my app through Uri association. Its as follows -

```
Uri uriToLaunch = new Uri("my-app-id:fblogin?access_token=12345678", 
                            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriToLaunch);
```

I get the access token by the above method.

But this does not happen through the fb app.

So is my understanding of the process of logging in using fb correct??

If so, what might I be doing wrong? if not, then what am I doing wrong??

all help is greatly appreciated.

thank you

SOLUTION:-

I setup wrong Uri association. It must be as follows -

```
<Protocol Name="msft-43245dd584d84cde837aa19a4a2e3914" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
```

In the "Name" field, it must be like msft-{Your-ProductID-Here}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This login flow will work only on phones which have beta version of facebook installed on them . So it wont be advisable to use this method for login. Still theres an article that describes how you can implement facebook login using Uri association. [Link](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login.aspx)

Comment: the latest facebook app is above version 5.2.  AFAIK the public / non-beta app now supports the above mentioned method. Is it not so???